# Is there an annotation similar to @SqsListener for SNS sending that initialises an executorservice and sets up multithreaded message sending?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

I am sending SNS messages from one spring boot app to another via a SQS queue. The listener is multi threaded by default as I can see the messages being read across multiple threads.
To send the SNS message I am using the ''' NotificationMessagingTemplate convertAndSend ''' method, which sends a SNS message on one thread.
Is there a similar annotation that I can use to send the SNS messages via an executor service, our do we have to set up the multi-threading ourselves to send SNS messages?